# Running shell script from java program is exiting with code 255

Tags: java, shell, cygwin

I am  running simple shell script from java program on cygwin terminal which runs fine but when i am passing the different shell script which takes 2 arguments is returning with exit code 255. The same shell script executes on cygwin terminal perfectly fine without java program.

Command used on cygwin terminal:
/cygdrive/c/Users/MYNAME/Documents/abcScript.sh -u "username" -p "password123"

Java program :

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe", "-c", "cd /bin/ ; abcScript.sh -u 'username' -p 'password123'" }, 
new String[] {"PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin"});

```
    StringBuilder output=new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        output.append(line+"\n");
    }
    int exitVal=proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println(exitVal);
    if(exitVal==0){
        System.out.println("Success");
        System.out.println(output);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("failed");
    }
    System.out.println(proc);


}
```

Comment: You can ask the process what's wrong by reading from `proc.getErrorStream()`

Comment: its giving json: command not found error on using getErrorStream(). But the same command works fine on cygwin terminal

Comment: In your program you do the equivalent of `export PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin`. You could try doing that in your terminal before running the command to see if the errors align

Comment: script not giving any error and running fine on cygwin terminal. Even the shell script is working on cmd terminal.

Comment: Which directory is your `json` command in?

Comment: How to check the path of json command .I have installed nodejs on path  'C:\Program Files\nodejs' under which npm is also installed . And installed json package by running command: 'npm install -g json'   on cygwin termianl . Earlier I was getting json: command not found error on running same script on cygwin . But after installing json package script ran successfully on cygwin.

Comment: In your terminal you can do `type json`

Comment: /cygdrive/c/Users/MY USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm/json

Comment: There you go. You are saying `PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin` so `json` isn't found because it's not in that directory. You could do `PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/MY USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm` . If you usually set your path in `.bashrc` or something, you can `source` that in the command to get the same environment as your terminal

Comment: Now getting error /cygdrive/c/Users/MY USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/npm/json: line 12: node: command not found

Comment: That's the same problem for a different command, and you can solve it in the same way. Alternatively, you can inspect your PATH in a terminal with `echo "$PATH"` and use the same value to avoid having to chase down each dependency. Again, you can probably `source ~/.bashrc` in your shell command to more closely mimic the interactive environment if you've already configured it in this file

Comment: Added path  of nodejs  "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs"  in code but now again program is exiting with 255 .                                                                   
My updated java code :                                                                            
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe", "-c", "cd /bin/ ; abcScript.sh " }, new String[] {"PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin;/cygdrive/c/Users/My Username/AppData/Roaming/npm;/cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs"});